# service nginx restart fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I checked the config syntax by run `nginx -t` then get the results:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

But when I run `service nginx restart` goes fail.

I have a config file named `a.com` in the sites-enabled folder, here's the content:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name a.com;

    # root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    # index index.html index.htm;
    root /home/a/public;

    client_max_body_size 10G;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

I'm at Ubuntu 14.10 and want to deploy a rails server.

Comment: Wha tis the error message you get when you do "service nginx restart"? You might just want to kill the process manually ("kill -9 [the-nginx-process-id]"), the try "service nginx start."

Comment: @kchan No error message. But I kill the process then start again as your suggest, the error disappears. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kill the nginx's process manually, then start nginx again, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and using `sudo` solved it:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

It might help to enable logs to checks the errors:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/

Comment: How have you come to the conclusion that it is a permissions issue?

Comment: @Wtower I had this problem and that command helps. (Edit: I had more clarity in my answer)